# Print dark background slides with light background

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am a fan of dark backgrounds and white text for slides. I think it works best when projected into a dark room.

But this is clearly not the best way for slides to be printed.

Is it possible to print the slides "inverted" with a light background and dark text?

More generally, is there a *print* theme and a *display* theme?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't pre-made print vs display themes but you could create and apply them.

You can also choose View | Grayscale or View | Black & White to see what your slides will look like on a b/w printer.

Then on the e.g. Grayscale tab, you can choose any shape or shapes and select the way you want it rendered from among the options in Change Selected Object.

This won't affect the appearance of the shapes when you print in color but will control how they look on a b/w printer.  You'll also see the effect in the preview on the print dialog.

This applies to Windows PowerPoint. Mac PPT may "think different".

Answer (score 0):

If you can export them to image files, you can try inverting the colours.

Also find out if your printer has an option to directly invert the print colours?